# ASP.NET Core Web API showing warning for no reason

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5. Just created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project.

Anytime I make changes to a file, I see the yellow warning icon on the file -- see below. App compiles and works fine so I'm trying to understand if VS is telling me something or this is a bug.

I don't seem to have this issue if the project is an ASP.NET Web application. The new app I created is Web API only.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the IDE? I notice some strangeness sometimes, too. Close and open seems to clear it. 15.4.1 just came out... maybe try the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those references are  pointing to some other location other than .csproj.

Delete them and add new references pointing to correct folder.

Then check the properties of the references in the solution explorer and check the path there.

EDIT:
Try restarting your IDE if the above solution does not solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. This is a brand new project and ValuesController is the generic controller a new ASP.NET API creates. Not sure how they could point to another location.

Comment: @Sam please indicate this as the accepted answer if this helped you. Thank you!

Comment: Restarted VS2017 in administrator mode and that fixed the icons. Then restarted in normal mode and all okay now.